# Как cделать вычитание дробей?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вообщем, задали нам калькулятор дробей. Всё получилось, *но* если 1\1 - 1\2 то выдает 0.
Я так и не нашел решение данной проблемы

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

def aaa(event):
    a = int(assq.get())
    b = int(ass1q.get())
    c = int(ass2q.get())
    d = int(ass3q.get())
    e = ass4q.get()
    z=b
    x=d
    while z!=x:
        if z>x:
            z=z-x
        else:
            x=x-z

    if z > x:
        qwerty=z*(b//z)*(d//z)
    else:
        qwerty=x*(b//x)*(d//x)


    if e == '+':

        pop1=((qwerty//b)*a)+((qwerty//d)*c)
        k = gcd(pop1,qwerty)

        if pop1 == 0:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='0'
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
        elif (pop1//k)>=(qwerty//k):
            labd2['text']=str((pop1//k)//(qwerty//k))
            laba['text']=str((pop1//k)%(qwerty//k))
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
            labd['text']='_'
        else:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='_'
            laba['text']=str(pop1//k)
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
        if lab['text']!='0'and((pop1//k)%(qwerty//k)) == 0:
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
            labd['text']=''
    ####################вот и вычитание#################################        
    if e == '-':
        pop2=((qwerty//b)*a)-((qwerty//d)*c)
        k = gcd(pop2,qwerty)

        if pop2 == 0:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='0'
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
        elif (pop2//k)>=(qwerty//k):
            labd2['text']=str((pop2//k)//(qwerty//k))
            laba['text']=str((pop2//k)%(qwerty//k))
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
            labd['text']='_'
        else:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='_'
            laba['text']=str(pop2//k)
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
        if lab['text']!='0'and((pop2//k)%(qwerty//k)) == 0:
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
            labd['text']='0'
    if e == '*':
        pop3=(a*c)
        qwerty=(b*d)
        k = gcd(pop3,qwerty)

        if pop3 == 0:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='0'
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
        elif (pop3//k)>=(qwerty//k):
            labd2['text']=str((pop3//k)//(qwerty//k))
            laba['text']=str((pop3//k)%(qwerty//k))
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
            labd['text']='_'
        else:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='_'
            laba['text']=str(pop3//k)
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
        if lab['text']!='0'and((pop3//k)%(qwerty//k)) == 0:
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
            labd['text']=''
    if e == ':':
        pop4=(a*d)
        qwerty=(c*b)
        k = gcd(pop4,qwerty)

        if pop4 == 0:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='0'
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
        elif (pop4//k)>=(qwerty//k):
            labd2['text']=str((pop4//k)//(qwerty//k))
            laba['text']=str((pop4//k)%(qwerty//k))
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
            labd['text']='_'
        else:
            labd2['text']=''
            labd['text']='_'
            laba['text']=str(pop4//k)
            lab['text']=str(qwerty//k)
        if lab['text']!='0'and((pop4//k)%(qwerty//k)) == 0:
            laba['text']=''
            lab['text']=''
            labd['text']=''

root = Tk()

root.geometry('400x400+100+100')
root.title('Okno')
root['bg']='#999999'

assq = Entry(root,width=5)
assq.place(x = 20, y = 1)

ass1q = Entry(root,width=5)
ass1q.place(x = 20, y = 29)

ass2q = Entry(root,width=5)
ass2q.place(x = 90, y = 1)

ass3q = Entry(root,width=5)
ass3q.place(x = 90, y = 29)

ass4q = Entry(root,width=5)
ass4q.place(x = 55, y = 15)

butq = Button(root,bg='blue',width=5, height=2)
butq.place(x = 187, y = 100)
butq.bind('<Button-1>',aaa)

laba = Label(root,font='Ariel 8',bg='#999999')
laba.place(x = 160, y = 1)
lab = Label(root,font='Ariel 8',bg='#999999')
lab.place(x = 160, y = 30)
labd = Label(root,font='Ariel 8',bg='#999999',text='_')
labd.place(x = 160, y = 16)
labd2 = Label(root,font='Ariel 8',bg='#999999')
labd2.place(x = 145, y = 16)
labd3 = Label(root,font='Ariel 10',bg='#999999',text='=')
labd3.place(x = 130, y = 16)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Целочисленное деление заменить на обычное

Comment: К сожилению нет, если заменить int на float то видает ошибки + дроби могут виглядеть... мягко скажем иначе

Comment: сделай нормальные имена переменным. невозможно читать.. qwerty это общий делитель ?

Comment: Да, qwerty - общий делитель

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вычитание дробей

```
 a/b - c/d
```

даёт числитель и знаменатель

```
nom = a * d - c * b
den = b * d
```

Их можно сократить (целочисленно разделить на наибольший общий делитель, если он больше 1)

Comment: Спасибо, большое

Comment: тоесть проблема в том что программист не правильно вычитал дроби?

Comment: @MBo, можно разделить на НОД в **любом** случае